# Non blocking object copy between S3 regions with the AWS PHP SDK v2

Tags: php, amazon-s3, guzzle, aws-php-sdk

I'm trying to copy large objects in Amazon S3 between buckets located in different regions using the `S3Client->copyObject()` operation in the AWS PHP SDK v2.

The object copying does works, but the problem is that the copy operation can take quite some time to return a response and it's blocking the PHP script's execution, which is not what I want in this particular case.

Is there any way to do the `copyObject()` call in a non-blocking way via the SDK (maybe with some lower level Guzzle settings)? I need this non-blocking behavior because I have to send regular health checks to another service (Amazon SWF) to let it know that my script is still running.

If the call can not be executed in a non-blocking way, I know there are other possible solutions but I'm looking to get more ideas from someone with more experience with the SDK.

(one possible approach that I think I could take is to `fork()` the process & do the `copyObject()` operation in a child process; also, some kind of progress callback would also work if Guzzle supports it and if it ensures the callback method is executed at least once every minute)

Comment: Not sure how you can use copyObject while you can't specify a region with copyObject(). Can you share code how you did this?

Comment: See [this official doc page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingREST.html). As far as I remember you need to send the request to the endpoint corresponding to the destination bucket.

Comment: Don't see any references to regions in there.

Comment: A bucket always belongs to a region. Specifying the source and destination bucket effectively specifies the source and destination region.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to create some process which will run in background.

You can use amazon queue service for this.

Check this link- http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/

**Solution 1-** You just need to provide job to queue service and it will execute your task in background so your PHP script don't need to wait.

**Solution 2-** There is another way is to have your PHP cron job that will execute after every minute or 5 minute. you can store your tasks in database and your cron will access tasks from DB and execute it.
**How it works** You just need to dump your task into DB and return. Then your cron will read from DB and execute it in background.

Comment: The code was already setup to run in the background as a PHP CLI process but it also needed to do other processing tasks without having to wait for the S3 copy operation to finish. This is why I needed a non-blocking call to copy the object between S3 buckets. I ended up using `fork()` and I plan to look into multipart copy operations between buckets to further improve on the copying speed.